# How To Repeat Rows Based On a Value in a Column In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to repeat data in cells from column B in column C if the value in Column A are "evc". With this code I end up with this

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(JOIN(" , ,",FILTER($B:$B, $A:$A = "evc"))),","))
```

[image: Not Wanted]

With this code I end up with this. I am new to Query commands and I don't know how to use the criteria.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(B1:B4&",", 2), ,999^99), ","))))
```

[image]

What I want instead is this. I think I need to use the repeat function but I can't figure out where to insert it.

[image: Wanted]

Comment: Give a try on `=INDEX(FILTER($B$1:B,$A$1:A="evc"),COUNTIF($A$1:A1,"evc"))`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ROW(B:B),FILTER({ROW(B:B),B:B},A:A="evc"),2,TRUE))
```

It's not entirely clear what you want however, so try sharing more of a sample.

Comment: I just want to show duplicate on the rows that have the value evc in the first column. This seemed to do the trick.